# Python socket and GET method of HTTP protocol?

Tags: python, sockets, http, protocols

I'm having a problem using the **GET** method of HTTP protocol, using **socket** library in python 3.8.2. My code:

```
import socket

mysocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysocket.connect(('www.w3.org',80))

msg = 'GET https://www.w3.org/Status.html HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n'
mysocket.sendall(msg.encode())

while True:
    data = mysocket.recv(1024)
    if (len(data)<1):
        break
    data.rstrip()
    print(data.decode())

mysocket.close()
```

It is supposed to prints the html code of w3.org/Status.html in the console but instead it returns a `Error 400 Bad Request`, here:

```
$ python web_navigator.py

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
date: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 02:13:59 GMT
last-modified: Thu, 26 Mar 2020 19:01:07 GMT
etag: "3f4-5a1c69b70a2c0"
accept-ranges: bytes
content-length: 1012
vary: upgrade-insecure-requests
content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

after this, shows a html page with the error `400`

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Host` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) is [mandatory](https://serverfault.com/questions/163511/what-is-the-mandatory-information-a-http-request-header-must-contain) for `HTTP/1.1`, and, as you are connecting `80` port, scheme should be `http`, so simply change your message to:

```
msg = 'GET http://www.w3.org/Status.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.w3.org\r\n\r\n'
```

Comment: It's not just the w3.org server, it's that HTTP/1.1 *requires* the `Host` header. See https://serverfault.com/questions/163511/what-is-the-mandatory-information-a-http-request-header-must-contain.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart thanks very much for rescuing me from forgetting this import knowledge

Comment: While based on the HTTP/1.1 specification a fully specified URL with method and domain might be fine, in practice many servers expect only the path here and the full URL is only used for proxy requests. Thus it should be `GET /Status.html ...` instead.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks for the completion, the http server of w3.org could handle [absolute form](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.3) resource well.